# Control.FromHandle for WPF

Tags: wpf, interop

Is there something like:

```
Control.FromHandle(IntPtr)
```

For WPF. This method is available for WinForms, so I'm just wondering if WPF has it too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most WPF elements do not create HWNDs, so this will usually only apply to top-level elements like Window.  You can use [HwndSource.FromHwnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.fromhwnd.aspx) to get the PresentationSource and then use the [RootVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.presentationsource.rootvisual.aspx) property to get the root of the visual tree:

```
var rootVisual = HwndSource.FromHwnd(hWnd).RootVisual;
```

Also see [WPF and Win32 Interoperation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx) for more details on how WPF uses HWNDs:

> All WPF elements on the screen are
>   ultimately backed by a HWND. When you
>   create a WPF Window, WPF creates a
>   top-level HWND, and uses an HwndSource
>   to put the Window and its WPF content
>   inside the HWND. The rest of your WPF
>   content in the application shares that
>   singular HWND. An exception is menus,
>   combo box drop downs, and other
>   pop-ups. These elements create their
>   own top-level window, which is why a
>   WPF menu can potentially go past the
>   edge of the window HWND that contains
>   it. When you use HwndHost to put an
>   HWND inside WPF, WPF informs Win32 how
>   to position the new child HWND
>   relative to the WPF Window HWND.